# how can we convert word to .pdf format and excel to .pdf format from c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

How can we convert the excel file and word file to .pdf format from c#. i tried the following  code but it shows the an error

this is my code:

```
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application appWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
   wordDocument = appWord.Documents.Open(@"C:\Users\ITPro2\Documents\test.docx");
   wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(@"D:\desktop\DocTo.pdf", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
```

and i got the following Error

`The export failed because this feature is not installed.` during export to pdf from word from c#

Comment: May I know what version of `Interop` object you used?

Comment: are all the C# tags necessary

Comment: Maybe better to use Aspose or an open source pdf-printer API

Comment: @balagurunath 14.0 am using

Comment: @lzzy . i didn't understand

Comment: @Michael i din't get u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not directly related the documentation under
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198122.aspx

gives a note, that if the pdf add-in is not installed, exactly this error will occur. So check your prerequisites, i.e. Office installed and the add-in, too.

Comment: can u explain it more

Comment: Like some other comments already explained: for the export to work you need a version of Microsoft Office installed that already has that pdf add-in(2010+) or an Office version plus that pdf add-in, f.e. for Office 2007: 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7

Answer (score 0):

1) [Excel 2013 Primary Interop Assembly Class Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn320445.aspx) and it works perfectly fine under .NET 4.5.1 Just add Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel assembly to your references and you are ready to go.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
namespace officeInterop
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application app = new Application();
            Workbook wkb = app.Workbooks.Open("d:\\x.xlsx");
            wkb.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, "d:\\x.pdf");
        }
    }
}
```

OR
2) refer this link to convert DOC or DOCx file into PDF

http://www.rasteredge.com/how-to/csharp-imaging/pdf-convert-word-to-pdf/

Comment: the raster edge libraries need to get, from where i can get it

Answer (score 0):

Since my other comment got deleted, here is the updated version.

For converting my files to pdf in c# i used the metamorphosis libary, this could also be a solution for you.

Below is a code example from me where i used a blobstorage to download PDF files from regular files.

```
var converter = new SautinSoft.PdfMetamorphosis();

var ms = new MemoryStream();
await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(ms);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

var pdfStream = converter.DocxToPdfConvertStream(ms);
if (pdfStream != null)
{
    await _storageProvider.SaveFileAsync(containerName, fileName, pdfStream);
}
ms.Close();

var result = await _storageProvider.GetFileWithAttributesAsync(containerName, fileName);
return new ServiceResponse<CloudBlockBlob>(result);
```

Below i posted some links with the sample code from the library itself:

- [Word to PDF example](https://sautinsoft.com/products/pdf-metamorphosis/examples/convert-docx-file-to-pdf-file-csharp-vb-net.php)
- [Excel to PDF example](https://sautinsoft.com/products/excel-to-pdf/examples/convert-excel-file-to-pdf-file-csharp-vb-net.php)